# Order of operations inside a function in js (vuejs)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to figure out creating a contact-list app in vuejs. One contact can have more than 1 address, email and number. So I have created input and a button to add another input if needed.

However, after the submit button is pressed I want to make only 1 input per unit (email,number,address) and want to empty its content, but it is overwriting the data I'm returning. I tried to do two separate funtions, that didn't help.

Here's the picture for the better understanding

[image]

`this.$emit` is the data I'm passing. Everything below that (in green box) clears inputs.

Also here is the code

```
onSubmit() {
  let numberValidation = this.numbers.map(el => el.value === "");
  let addressValidation = this.addresses.map(el => el.value === "");
  let emailsValidation = this.emails.map(el => el.value === "");

  let len =
    numberValidation.length +
    addressValidation.length +
    emailsValidation.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (
      numberValidation[i] === true ||
      addressValidation[i] === true ||
      emailsValidation[i] === true ||
      this.title.trim() === ""
    ) {
      return this.$alert("you have an empty space");
      break;
    }
  }
  const newContact = [
    {
      name: this.title,
      number: this.numbers,
      address: this.addresses,
      email: this.emails
    }
  ];

  this.$emit("newcontact", newContact);

  this.title = "";
  this.numbers.length = this.addresses.length = this.emails.length = 1;
  this.numbers[0].value = this.addresses[0].value = this.emails[0].value =
    "";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays in `newContact` for `number`, `address` and `email` are the same arrays that you then modify a few lines later.

There are various ways you could fix this but the key is to use different arrays.

In your specific example I'd probably go with something like this:

```js
this.numbers = [{ value: '' }];
this.addresses = [{ value: '' }];
this.emails = [{ value: '' }];
```

Note that this assigns new arrays containing new objects to the properties, it doesn't mutate the original arrays or the objects within them.

It's unclear from your code whether the objects have other properties but if they only have a `value` then this should be sufficient.